# how to fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, compiler-errors

im trying to make a snake ai that can see where itself is so im using this code to try and do that

im sorta new to python

```
                if new_direction == "Right" and new_head_position - (0, 20) in self.snake_positions:
                    if new_direction == "Right" and new_head_position + (0, 20) in self.snake_positions:
                        self.direction = "Right"
```

i expect the code to set self.direction to "Right" only if the other spaces are occupied by snake parts but im getting this error

Comment: Please show us enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions will produce errors: `new_head_position - (0, 20)` and `new_head_position + (0, 20)`, as Python doesn't allow you to perform arithmetic operations between tuples.

Here is a workaround for you:

```
(new_head_position[0], new_head_position[1] - 20)
(new_head_position[0], new_head_position[1] + 20)
```